# Create Only Audio Calling Using OpenVidu

Tags: ionic3, openvidu

I want only audio calling without using webcam. But the following code only work with camera permission.When I removed camera permission then it's not called **streamCreated** event.

```
   const publisher: Publisher = this.OV.initPublisher(undefined, {
      audioSource: undefined, // The source of audio. If undefined default microphone
      videoSource: undefined, // The source of video. If undefined default webcam
      publishAudio: true, // Whether you want to start publishing with your audio unmuted or not
      publishVideo: false, // Whether you want to start publishing with your video enabled or not
      resolution: '640x480', // The resolution of your video
      frameRate: 30, // The frame rate of your video
      insertMode: 'APPEND', // How the video is inserted in the target element 'video-container'
      mirror: true // Whether to mirror your local video or not
    });
```

I am using Ionic for android application

Answer (score 2):

You need to set 'videoSource' to 'false' rather than 'undefined'.
Something like this should work :

```
const publisher: Publisher = this.OV.initPublisher(undefined, {
      audioSource: undefined, // The source of audio. If undefined default microphone
      videoSource: false, // The source of video. If undefined default webcam
      publishAudio: true, // Whether you want to start publishing with your audio unmuted or not
      publishVideo: false, // Whether you want to start publishing with your video enabled or not
      resolution: '640x480', // The resolution of your video
      frameRate: 30, // The frame rate of your video
      insertMode: 'APPEND', // How the video is inserted in the target element 'video-container'
      mirror: true // Whether to mirror your local video or not
    });
```